# Trace Class (Obsolete!)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider ONB's $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{S}'$.

> For trace class it is:
>   $$\operatorname{Tr}A<\infty:\quad\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}}\langle A\sigma,\sigma\rangle=\sum_{\sigma'\in\mathcal{S}'}\langle A\sigma',\sigma'\rangle$$
>   How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal S$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $|A|$ (this exists, since $|A|$ is trace-class and thus compact). Let $\mathcal T$ be any other orthonormal basis. For any $\sigma\in\mathcal S$, we have
$$
|A|\sigma=s_\sigma(A)\,\sigma
$$
and $\sum_\sigma s_\sigma(A)=\sum_\sigma\langle |A|\sigma,\sigma\rangle<\infty$.

Then, for any $B\in B(H)$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{\sigma}\langle BA\sigma,\sigma\rangle
&=\sum_{\sigma}\left\langle B\left(\sum_{\sigma'}\langle A\sigma,\sigma'\rangle\,\sigma'\right),\sigma\right\rangle\\ \ \\
&\textit{(continuity of $B$ and of the inner product)}\\ \ \\
&=\sum_{\sigma}\sum_{\sigma'}\left\langle \langle A\sigma,\sigma'\rangle\,B\sigma',\sigma\right\rangle
=\sum_{\sigma}\sum_{\sigma'} \langle A\sigma,\sigma'\rangle\,\langle B\sigma',\sigma\rangle\\ \ \\
&\textit{(the sums can be interchanged because of absolute convergence; see below)}\\ \ \\
&=\sum_{\sigma'}\sum_{\sigma} \langle A\sigma,\sigma'\rangle\,\langle B\sigma',\sigma\rangle\\ \ \\
&=\sum_{\sigma}\langle AB\sigma,\sigma\rangle.
\end{align}

Now, back to your problem, let $U$ be a unitary that sends $\mathcal S$ to $\mathcal T$. Then
$$
\sum_{\tau\in\mathcal T}\langle A\tau,\tau\rangle
=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal S}\langle AU\sigma,U\sigma\rangle
=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal S}\langle U^*AU\sigma,\sigma\rangle
=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal S}\langle AUU^*\sigma,\sigma\rangle
=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal S}\langle A\sigma,\sigma\rangle
$$

---

For the justification that the double sum converges absolutely, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{\sigma}\sum_{\sigma'} |\langle A\sigma,\sigma'\rangle\,\langle B\sigma',\sigma\rangle|
&\leq\sum_\sigma\left(\sum_{\sigma'}|\langle A\sigma,\sigma'\rangle|^2 \right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{\sigma'}|\langle B\sigma',\sigma\rangle|^2 \right)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&=\sum_\sigma\|A\sigma\|\,\|B^*\sigma\|\leq\|B\|\,\sum_\sigma\|\,|A|\sigma\|\\ \ \\
&\leq \|B\|\,\sum_\sigma s_\sigma(A)<\infty.
\end{align}
(note that $\|A\sigma\|^2=\langle A^*A\sigma,\sigma\rangle=\langle|A|^2\sigma,\sigma\rangle=\|\,|A|\sigma\|^2$).

Comment: Now what about the step $\sum_\sigma\|B\sigma\|\,\|A^*\sigma\|\leq\|B\|\sum_\sigma\langle A^*A\sigma,\sigma\rangle$? I'm getting only a root $\|A\sigma\|=\sqrt{\langle A^*A\sigma,\sigma\rangle}$.

Comment: Yes, the argument should be a little different. Please give me a couple minutes.

Comment: No problem! The problem is the very first split into separate expressions for A and B that gives Cauchy Schwarz leading directly to Hilbert Schmidt instead of trace class. Let me know if you have something. *(I'm working on it to fix it too.)*

Comment: That's not exactly the issue: trace-class operators are always Hilbert-Schmidt (the same as $\ell^1(\mathbb N)\subset\ell^2(\mathbb N)$). But the idea I had doesn't seem to work. I know a totally different approach, but I have no more time today, sorry.

Comment: Yes that looks good. Thanks! Do you think it is possible to circumvent the SVD while not complicating the problem too much? *(I'm thinking of something like the earlier proofs on projections not using Gelfand-Naimark.)* Besides, if you don't mind, I'd like to make an extra thread with your answer on the algebra of trace class operators while focusing here on the line with the $U$ and $U^*$. That would be less distractive and highlight your idea of this proof here. Any case: (+1) :)

Comment: You make sound sophisticated by calling it Singular Value Decomposition. What is needed in my argument is just the fact that the spectrum of a compact operator consists only of eigenvalues. That's pretty basic, in my view, and I don't immediately see a way to avoid it.

Comment: And that the eigenvalues correspond to mutually orthogonal eigenvectors that form an ONB. That was just because the absolute of the operator was not only compact but also selfadjoint. That is more than just the spectrum consists only of eigenvalues, that is the SVD. Else the failure sits in the formula:$\sum_\sigma s_\sigma=\sum_\sigma\|A\sigma\|$

Comment: As examples regard the basic nilpotents $N=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $N=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$. Both are compact and their spectrum is pure point. But the former has one eigenvector only while the latter has not mutually orthogonal eigenvectors.

Comment: I trimmed the comment tree in response to a system flag on the number of comments. Let me (or another mod) now if I deleted something critical.